# Drawing per-pixel into a backbuffer or texture to display to screen, using opengl - no glDrawPixels()

Tags: arrays, opengl, textures, render-to-texture

Basically, I have an array of data (fluid simulation data) which is generated per-frame in real-time from user input (starts in system ram). I want to write the density of the fluid to a texture as an alpha value - I interpolate the array values to result in an array the size of the screen (the grid is relatively small) and map it to a 0 - 255 range. What is the most efficient way (ogl function) to write these values into a texture for use?

Things that have been suggested elsewhere, which I don't think I want to use (please, let me know if I've got it wrong):

1. glDrawPixels() - I'm under the impression that this will cause an interrupt each time I call it, which would make it slow, particularly at high resolutions.
2. Use a shader - I don't think that a shader can accept and process the volume of data in the array each frame (It was mentioned elsewhere that the cap on the amount of data they may accept is too low)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, both solutions are over-complicating the issue. Am I correct in thinking you've already generated an array of size x*y where x and y are your screen resolution, filled with unsigned bytes ?

If so, if you want an OpenGL texture that uses this data as its alpha channel, why not just create a texture, bind it to GL_TEXTURE_2D and call [glTexImage2D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) with your data, using GL_ALPHA as the format and internal format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE as the type and (x,y) as the size ?

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think a shader would perfom bad? The whole idea of shaders is about processing huge amounts of data very, very fast. Please use Google on the search phrase "General Purpose GPU computing" or "GPGPU".

Shaders can only gather data from buffers, not scatter. But what they can do is change values in the buffers. This allows for a (fragment) shader to write the locations of *GL_POINT*s, which are then in turn placed on the target pixels of the texture. Shader Model 3 and later GPUs can also access texture samplers from the geometry and vertex shader stages, so the fragment shader part gets really simple then.

If you just have a linear stream of positions and values, just send those to OpenGL through a Vertex Array, drawing *GL_POINT*s, with your target texture being a color attachment for a framebuffer object.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most efficient way (ogl function) to write these values into a texture for use?

A good way would be to try to avoid any unnecessary extra copies. So you could use [Pixel Buffer Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) which you [map to your address space](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping), and use that to directly *generate* your data into.

Since you want to update this data per frame, you also want to look for efficient [buffer object streaming](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming), so that you don't force implicit synchronizations between the CPU and GPU. An easy way to do that in your scenario would be using a ring buffer of 3 PBOs, which you advance every frame.

> Things that have been suggested elsewhere, which I don't think I want to use (please, let me know if I've got it wrong):
>
> 1. glDrawPixels() - I'm under the impression that this will cause an interrupt each time I call it, which would make it slow, particularly at high resolutions.

Well, what the driver does is totally implementation-specific. I don't think that the "cause an interrupt each time" is a useful mental image here. You seem to completely underestimate the work the GL implementation will be doing behind your back. A GL call will not correspond to some command which is sent to the GPU.

But not using `glDrawPixels` is still a good choice. It is not very efficient, and it has been deprecated and *removed* from modern GL.

> 2. Use a shader - I don't think that a shader can accept and process the volume of data in the array each frame (It was mentioned elsewhere that the cap on the amount of data they may accept is too low)

You got this totally wrong. There is no way to *not* use a shader. If you're not writing one yourself (e.g. by using old "fixed-function pipeline" of the GL), the GPU driver will provide the shader for you. The hardware implementation for these earlier fixed function stages has been completely superseeded by programmable units - so if you can't do it with shaders, you can't do it with the GPU. And I would strongly recommend to write your own shader (it is the only option in modern GL, anyway).